# Отрицание Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть две таблицы
1 - users, поля id,name
2 - auth_assignment, поля id,user_id, auth_name

завязка id - user_id. Я могу сделать вот такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN auth_assignment ON (users.id = auth_assignment.user_id)
WHERE auth_assignment.auth_name = "admin"
```

И мне нужно полное отрицание то есть вытащить все кроме тех строк где есть соответствие по полю auth_name = "admin"

И желательно на синтаксисе Yii2 active record, но можно и чистый mysql код

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите операторы sql - их не шибко много, чтобы не помнить про существование оператора "не равно":

```
auth_assignment.auth_name != "admin"
```

Comment: или такой оператор не равенстав `<>`